# QGIS Server Installation Fail

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx

I'm trying to install QGIS Serveur on Ubuntu.
I have followed this tutorial but it is not complet :
https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/server/getting_started.html#nginx

I'm with Nginx and I try first with Systemd (seems to me to be the most recent way of doing it) but I have a fail when I do :

```
sudo systemctl start qgis-server@sockets.service
```

```
qgis-server@sockets.service: Got no socket.
qgis-server@sockets.service: Failed to run 'start' task: Invalid argument
qgis-server@sockets.service: Failed with result 'resources'.
Failed to start QGIS Server Service (instance sockets).
```

I don't know what's wrong here

---

Then I try to setup QGIS Server with `spawn-fcgi`.
I follow the instructions and do the command with `spawn-fcgi`.

When I got to `localhost/qgisserver` I got this response :

```
<ServerException>Project file error</ServerException>
```

---

I don't know if it's the correct. The tutorial doesn't give any kind of information here about what to except.

I then jump to the part "Serve a project", modified the url to fit the location where I put the demo project. Unfortunately I only have a with rectangle and not the map.

Any idea how can I fix all that ?

EDIT : I try the installation with Apache instead of Nginx and I came to the same issue, a white rectangle.